# Visual Studio 2019 EnvDTE.DTE (C#): Creating new project in current solution by cloning existing project fails

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working on creating a testing pipeline which automatically pasts a piece of code into a newly created Unit Test Project so that a user can conveniently run Microsoft's auto-test generation tool (`IntelliTest`) on it. I am working on developing the auto Unit Test Project generation component, and in my existing Visual Studio solution, I have manually created a new Unit Test Project with the exact specifications of what I want (UnitTestTemplate).

I then perform the following steps:

1. Retrieve the current Visual Studio solution.
2. Add a new project based upon the UnitTestTemplate csproj file, by using the `AddFromFile` method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._solution.addfromfile?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) on the solution.

Below is my code:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
EnvDTE._Solution solution = dte.Solution;
solution.AddFromFile("C:/NewestCode/TestingAutomation/src/UnitTestGeneration/UnitTestTemplate/UnitTestTemplate.csproj");
```

However, at Step 2, which is at this line: `solution.AddFromFile("C:/NewestCode/TestingAutomation/src/UnitTestGeneration/UnitTestTemplate/UnitTestTemplate.csproj");`,

I get the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unspecified error
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))

This seems strange, considering that I know my file path for the `.csproj` file is correct.